# Creating a function to set 'nan' values

Tags: python, pandas, function, merge

I am trying to create a function to set nan values specific columns as follows:

```
 def set_nan_for_specific_column(table, column):
    result = table[str(column)] = np.nan
    return result

merged_table['code'] = set_nan_for_specific_column(merged_table, code)
```

I get the following error:

```
 NameError: name 'code' is not defined
```

any suggestions anyone?

Comment: You're calling your function passing code, which you didn't define earlier.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see the problem comes from this line:

```
merged_table['code'] = set_nan_for_specific_column(merged_table, code)
```

Indeed you give to the function the argument `code` which has never been defined before and then leading to an error. Even if you change the dtype of `code` afterwards to obtain `'col'` in order to select the columns named `code` from your df, when calling the fucntion `set_nan_for_specific_column` , it will search for a variable named `col`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

the parameters code, that I put between stars is not defined:

```
    merged_table['code'] = set_nan_for_specific_column(merged_table, **code**)
```

Moreover, notice that in this way you will add two new columns to your dataframe. One is "code", the other one will be the value contained inside the variable code.
for example:

```
    code = "z"
    df['code'] = set_nan_for_specific_column(df, code)
```

Will give you these 2 new columns:
`z` and `code`